# SQL: Discard rows with conflicting records in one column

Tags: sql, oracle

To better illustrate my problem, I came up with a sample scenario shown below:

The following is a list of bank account history for customer A and B. The Open_Year for some of the accounts are either missing or conflicting with other records.

For example, account **A-3-UB** represents a single account with two records in the list, however, it has two conflicting Open_Year 1990 & 2012; account **A-1-BA** has two records, where one of the records is missing the Open_Year.

```
Customer Account_id Bank_id Open_Year Gender
       A          1      BA      2000      F
       A          1      BA         .      F

       A          2      UB         .      F

       A          3      UB      1990      F
       A          3      UB      2012      F

       A          4      UB      2013      F
       A          4      UB      2013      .

       A          5      UB         .      F

       B          1      WF      2014      M
       B          1      WF      2014      .

       B          6      WF         .      .
```

What I would like to have is through a single **SELECT** query, those accounts with either missing/conflicting Open_Year will be discarded completed, i.e., the return result will be:

```
 Customer Account_id Bank_id Open_Year Gender
        A          4      UB      2013      F
        A          4      UB      2013      .
        B          1      WF      2014      M
        B          1      WF      2014      .
```

**Additional Question:**

Now we have another record been added at the end, and we'd also like to discard a row when **Gender** is conflicting or missing at least one value, same requirement as for Open_Year:

```
Customer Account_id Bank_id Open_Year Gender
       A          1      BA      2000      F
       A          1      BA         .      F

       A          2      UB         .      F

       A          3      UB      1990      F
       A          3      UB      2012      F

       A          4      UB      2013      F
       A          4      UB      2013      .

       A          5      UB         .      F

       B          1      WF      2014      M
       B          1      WF      2014      .

       B          6      WF         .      .

       C          7      WB      2015      F
```

The expected output would be:

```
Customer Account_id Bank_id Open_Year Gender
       C          7      WB      2015      F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also you can use group by and having like this:

```
with a(Customer,Account_id,Bank_id,Open_Year,Gender) as (
select       'A'      ,    '1'   ,   'BA'  ,    2000,     'F' from dual union all
select       'A'      ,    '1'   ,   'BA'  ,    null ,    'F' from dual union all
select       'A'      ,    '2'   ,   'UB'  ,    null ,    'F' from dual union all
select       'A'      ,    '3'   ,   'UB'  ,    1990 ,    'F' from dual union all
select       'A'      ,    '3'   ,   'UB'  ,    2012 ,    'F' from dual union all
select       'A'      ,    '4'   ,   'UB'  ,    2013 ,    'F' from dual union all
select       'A'      ,    '4'   ,   'UB'  ,    2013 ,     null from dual union all
select       'A'      ,    '5'   ,   'UB'  ,    null ,    'F'   from dual union all
select       'B'      ,    '1'   ,   'WF'  ,    2014 ,    'M'   from dual union all
select       'B'      ,    '1'   ,   'WF'  ,    2014 ,     null from dual union all
select       'B'      ,    '6'   ,   'WF'  ,    null ,     null from dual union all
select       'C'      ,    '7'   ,   'AC'  ,    2016,      'F' from dual)
select a.*
  from a
 where (account_id, bank_id, Open_Year) in 
       ( select account_id, bank_id , Open_Year 
           from a 
          group by account_id, bank_id , Open_Year
         having count(*) > 1 )

    or customer in (select customer from a group by customer having count(*) = 1)
```

Comment: The error returned says: A subquery cannot select more than one column.

Comment: i tested it on oracle 11g and 10xe (in 10xe need some modify in with aliasing) and it's work as expect. no error about subquery.

Comment: I just tested it again and it worked very well for the sample dataset! One additional question: is it possible to filter by two columns (let's say: Open_Year, Gender) at the same time in a single query?

Comment: if i understand you right, yes, you can like this `... and (Open_Year, Gender) in (select Open_Year, Gender from ... ) ..` or you can in separate condition like this `.. and Open_Year = something and Gender = something ..`

Comment: what if we have a new record: 'C', '7', 'AC', 2016, 'F'. The code will drop this record, while I wanted to keep it since there's not conflict nor missing value for this record..

Comment: add at the end `or customer in (select customer from a group by customer having count(*) = 1)`

Comment: This is a very good solution, exactly what I'm looking for to solve my extended problems! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using window functions.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(distinct open_year) over (partition by account_id, bank_id) as cntd_oy,
             count(*) over (partition by account_id, bank_id) as cnt,
             count(open_year) over (partition by account_id, bank_id) as cnt_oy
      from t
     ) t
where cntd_oy = 1 and cnt = cnt_oy
```

Comment: @YMing . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  As the OP, you can accept whichever answer you like, but I am curious why.

Comment: @YMing You need three more counters: all, not null, and distinct.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I apologize for the confusion. I turned to Анатолий Предеин's solution because his method doesn't require the creation of intermediate counters. Although yours is very straight forward and neat as well. For my extended problem, I tried to create an additional counter for variable Gender - cnt_gd, attempted to let cnt = min(cnt_oy, cnt_gd), however, the grouping seems to be an issue for this case that I haven't worked out yet..

Comment: @YMing . . . Normally analytic functions are faster than aggregations and `in`, but thank you for the explanation.